# android - align a textview to the center of another view

Tags: android, android-layout

i have some imagebuttons and each one has a corresponding textview, i'd like to align those textview's to the center of their corresponding imageview, i mean, like is seen on the app drawer...

```
 !-----!
 !icon !
 !_____!
app  name
```

this is my code, i'm using a `RelativeLayout`

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/blog_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo_img"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/blog_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/blog" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/blog_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blog_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/blog_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/blog_desc" />
```

Comment: This can be done using constraint layout:
you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51068096/9121129) link.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Wrap that in a `LinearLayout` and center the children, like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo_img"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/blog_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/blog_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/blog" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blog_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/blog_desc" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks!! how i didn't think of this? a sublayout... i'm still learning but i feel stupid right now... :/

Comment: Jason, for future reference, [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) should generally not be used for holding multiple children. A `LinearLayout` would be the best substitute in this case.

Comment: i wasn't planning on using a `FrameLayout` anyway, but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Eric Why's that? A `FrameLayout` is a great way to achieve what Hairo wants. A `LinearLayout` would not work because you cannot overlap children views. An alternative `ViewGroup` could be `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Or have I misunderstood the question? Do you want the text centered on the image, or just horizontally centered on the image?

Comment: @Hairo Apologies. After rereading your question I did misunderstand what you wanted to achieve. Eric was correct that the best solution is a `LinearLayout` in this case.

Answer (score 18):

Old post but if this can help I think it's not necessary to add an additional container.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/blog_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo_img"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/blog_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/blog" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/blog_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blog_button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/blog_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/blog_button"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
    android:text="@string/blog_desc" />
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If a the TextView can be transparent then this can be achieved with a single View

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test string"
    android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textSize="10sp"
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

If your views in `RelativeLayout` follow these steps:

1- wrap your view that wants to be aligned in the center of target view in Framelayout.

2- move all layout attributes to FrameLayout.

3- set `layout_align_top` and `layout_align_bottom` (or start and end if horizontal) to target view.

4- set `layout_gravity` to `center_vertical` (or `horizontal`) to child of Frame layout

Result:
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/yourView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

    <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/masseur_rating_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ic_selector_rating_bar"
            android:rating="@{masseurItem.rate}"
            android:scaleX="0.8"
            android:scaleY="0.8"
            tools:rating="4.5" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rate_text_view"
            style="@style/BodyTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/masseur_rating_bar"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(masseurItem.rate)}"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="4.5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```