# ConstraintLayout: how to center a view under another and also stay within parent bounds?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to center a view under another like this "sign out" button under the email:

[image: centered views]

I did this by using a `ConstraintLayout` as the parent and constraining the bottom view's left and right edges to the left and right edges of the top view. This properly centers the two views. (Note that I *don't* want to center the views in the parent.)

The problem I'm having is that if the top view is narrow, the bottom view can end up truncated on the right by the parent, as here (from the layout editor):

[image: badly positioned view]

I don't know in advance how narrow the top view will be at run time. (It won't necessarily be an email address, and, even if it were, I know someone whose email address is only 8 characters!)

I would like to set up constraints so that the bottom view is centered under the top view, but if it ends up too far to the right, it shifts left just enough to avoid crossing a guideline. The right edge of the top view needs to remain fixed. How can I achieve this effect? (I'm not wedded to using a `ConstraintLayout` if there's another way that will work better.)

Here's the actual layout file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="user"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/scrim"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:text="@string/sign_out"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_name"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @Enzokie - Unfortunately, that would allow the trailing edge of the top view to shift to the left. My current choice is to eliminate the constraint between the start of the bottom view and the start of the top view. That sacrifices the centering (which is an issue) but solves the truncation problem (which is a bigger issue). Not fully satisfactory, but I can live with it if I have to.

Comment: If there is only such thing as `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias_MAX="1.0"` this should be easier.

Comment: This [code](https://hastebin.com/royolabubi.xml) works at [shorter text](http://i.imgur.com/K3LOO2K.png) and when the [text is longer](http://i.imgur.com/sLRtuIB.png) compare to the button it centers the button.

Comment: @Enzokie - Yes, that works. It's basically the same as [Ben P.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45341850/535871) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds to me like a case where `ConstraintLayout` isn't the best tool for the job. You might still wind up using `ConstraintLayout` as your top-level view, but to get what you want I believe you will have to nest your `TextView` and `Button` inside a LinearLayout.

The core of the problem is that you want whichever view is wider to touch the edge of the parent, and whichever view is smaller to be horizontally centered against the wider view. Given that `ConstraintLayout` doesn't let you do more than one constraint for a given view's edge, it's not capable of doing this.

A vertical `LinearLayout` with `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` should do exactly what you want, however. And then you can position that at the top-right of your screen (maybe by using `ConstraintLayout`, or maybe some other way).

### Edit

After re-reading your question, I realize I misunderstood your requirements. You need the `TextView` to always be positioned in the top-right corner, and the `Button` to be centered beneath the text view unless that would cause it to be clipped by the edge of the parent.

I still think `LinearLayout` is the way to go here, but you'll need to be  a little more sophisticated with its children. This should work:

```
<ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        constrants=top-right>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This nicely fixes the layout issue. Thanks. While this helps, I can't use it directly because grouping the text view and the button like that interferes with event handling. (The scrim needs to be sandwiched in Z between the top and bottom views.)

Comment: What purpose does the scrim serve? It looks like it covers the whole parent, but I don't see what you need it for (since in the example it is transparent).

Comment: It's there to intercept all touch events outside the bottom view. The scrim and the bottom view change visibility in sync. When their visibility is set to `VISIBLE`, I want any tap outside the bottom view to dismiss both the bottom view and the scrim (visibility set to `GONE`). It's also possible that as our app evolves, the scrim will change from transparent to translucent (when visible). As I'm thinking about it, perhaps I can use your solution after all, by modifying the click handler for the top view to trigger the dismiss logic if the bottom view/scrim are visible. Ugly, but it may work.

Comment: Another option is to essentially use two scrims. One between the button and the text, and another behind that grouped layout. Clicking either would dismiss both.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there are 2 views.

- Select **first view**
- Press **shift**
- Select the **second view**.
- **Right click**
- Select **Align** >> **Horizontal Centers**.

Done.

Comment: This solution does not work. If you read through the question, you'll see that the problem is that sometimes, depending on the content of the views (which changes at run time) the views must *not* be centered with respect to one another.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't get you perfectly, but I'm posting the answer for what I understood.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="user"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:text="SIGNOUT"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_name"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/user_name"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/user_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here it is try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="user@mail.com"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/scrim"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"


    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_out"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:text="sign_out"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_name"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: From what I can tell, all this does is add a right margin of 11dp to the bottom view. This will just throw off the centering (when the top view is wide enough) and won't stop the truncation (when the top view is too narrow).